# Java FX TranslateTransition Duration change

Tags: java, javafx

So I want to be able to change speed of my animation by changing the Duration. I know that Java Docs say that it can't be done, but I don't see any problem with stopping the animation, changing the Duration and starting from the point where it stopped. With this implementation my circle simply stops, and doesn't want to move any more. Can I do it somehow? If I can't, how can I make an animation which has changable speed?

EDIT:
It actually works, but when I change the Duration, then the starting point changes, and the ending point doesn't so it gets closer and closer to the ending point until it stops (unless I only change the speed when the circle is close to initial starting point). Any ideas for an algorithm that would only affect the speed of the animation?

```java
public void initialize() { 
          TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition();
          transition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
          transition.setToX(162);
          transition.setToY(72);
          transition.setAutoReverse(true);
          transition.setCycleCount(TranslateTransition.INDEFINITE);
          transition.setNode(myCircle);
          transition.play();


        mySlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {

                transition.stop();
                Duration d = transition.getDuration();
                transition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(mySlider.getValue()));
                transition.playFrom(d);
                System.out.println(mySlider.getValue());

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> EDIT: It actually works, but when I change the Duration, then the starting point changes, and the ending point doesn't so it gets closer and closer to the ending point until it stops (unless I only change the speed when the circle is close to initial starting point).

Since you do not specify the starting value of `translateX` and `translateY`, `TranslateTransition` gets the current values of these properties at the time of transitioning from the stopped state to another state. Since you do stop the transition, this happens for every change of the slider. At that time the value of the translate properties may be different from the starting position.
Furthermore the time you pass to the `playFrom` method may be after the end of the cycle, if you decrease the duration slider's value.

I recommend modifying the [`rate` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/animation/Animation.html#rateProperty) instead:

```
TranslateTransition transition = new TranslateTransition();
transition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
...

transition.rateProperty().bind(Bindings.divide(1d, mySlider.valueProperty()));
```